# Rescaling time for rates in a nonhomogenous Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

If I have a non homogeneous Poisson process, say $N_{1}(t)$, with rate $\lambda_{1}(t)$ and I rescale the time  by some function, $s=f(t)$, is the following correct? $\lambda_{2}(t)$ denotes the rate function of the rescaled process $N_{2}(t)=N_{1}(f(t))$.

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{2}(t)=\lambda_{1}(f(t)))\frac{d}{d t}f(t)
\end{equation}

I take the rate to be $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1)}{h}$.

I can see this appears to be some sort of chain rule, but I'm struggling to show it formally.

Edit:
After accepting the answer, I thought I'd put an example here and my attempt at a proof. Let $N_{1}(t)$ have rate $\lambda_{1}(t)=t^{2}$ and let $a(t)=\frac{t^{3}}{3}$ (the mean). We know that $N_{1}(a^{-1}(t))$ is a rate 1 Poisson process ($\lambda_{2}(t)=1$). Check: $\frac{d a^{-1}(t)}{dt}=(3t)^{-2/3}$, while $\lambda_{1}(a_{1}(t))=(3t)^{2/3}$ verifiying the above expression.

To show the expression
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{2}(t)dt=P(N_{2}(t+dt)=k+1|N_{2}(t)=k)=P(N_{1}(f(t+dt))=k+1|N_{1}(f(t))=k)
\\
=\text{exp}\bigg(-\int_{f(t)}^{f(t+dt)}\lambda_{1}(f(t'))dt'\bigg)\bigg(\int_{f(t)}^{f(t+dt)}\lambda_{1}(f(t'))dt'\bigg)=\lambda_{1}(f(t))\frac{df}{dt}dt
\end{equation}
where all equalities are to leading order in $dt$

Comment: If you want to be formal, you might want to explain what $\lambda(s)$ means in your proposed formula? One cannot expect the intensity of the original process at times $t$ and $f(t)$ to be related by this.

Comment: $\lambda(s)=\lambda(f(t))$ where $\lambda,f$ are some smooth functions.

Comment: Yeah, and you really expect $\lambda(t)$ and $\lambda(f(t))$ to be related by the identity in your post? For example, every function $\lambda$ is such that $\lambda(t)=2\lambda(2t)$... and such that $\lambda(t)=2t\lambda(t^2)$... hence $\lambda(2)=2\lambda(4)=4\lambda(4)$? Ad lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct and it's not quite a chain rule. Rather, over a small time interval $\Delta t$, the probability of getting an event over that time interval is approximately $\Delta t \lambda(t)$. When you make the time warping change, the time becomes $f(t)$ so the rate becomes $\lambda(f(t))$ for given $t$ but the small time interval width becomes approximately $f'(t) \Delta t$ by definition of the derivative.

UPDATE: Per the comments, I should clarify. I am assuming that the new rate $\lambda_1 (t)$ as a function of $t$, obtained after time warping, is not $\lambda (t)$ where $\lambda$ is the original rate function.

Comment: ie because "$df=f'(t) dt$"?

Comment: Sure that's another way of saying it, if you accept infinitessimals in formulas

Comment: $\lambda=\lambda$?

Comment: @Did I've noticed you make a lot of very insightful comments so I pay extra attention when you have something to say, but I'm not following you on that one. Can you elaborate?

Comment: See comment on question.

Comment: @Did ok now I get it. I interpreted the question as to what the new rate (new $\lambda$) would be as a function of $t$, assuming that $t$ was replaced by $f(t)$ in the original $\lambda$ function. To me $\lambda$ on the right is the original function and $\lambda$ on the left is the new rate as a function of $t$. It would be better to use different $\lambda$ symbols on each side of the equation, I agree.

Comment: Indeed -- different symbols for different objects would be nice.

Comment: Apologies, I see the error of my ways.

Comment: @Michael Nothing prevents you to rewrite the question in line with these remarks, right? I would even go as far as suggesting you do that.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the time you've both put into this so far, if you could give your agreement to my edits, that be great.